# Run Mockserver behind Nginx Reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, mockserver

I'm trying to run Mockserver behind a nginx reverse but when I'm tryning to acces the Dashboard of mockserver through the proxy i'm getting a blank page.

my config :
Mockserver : 172.30.10.30:1080
Nginx server : 172.30.10.31

nginx.cfg :

```
server {
        listen   8080;
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name     172.30.10.31;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/aci-proxy-01.indus.ad.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/aci-proxy-01.indus.ad.key;

#       proxy_http_version 1.1;
#       proxy_buffers 16 16k;
#       proxy_buffer_size 16k;

        keepalive_timeout 100;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

        add_header      Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header      X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header      X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff;

location ~ ^/stack1/mockserver/(.*)$  {
                proxy_pass              http://172.30.10.30:1080/mockserver/$1;



        }
}
```

here is the content of acces.log :

```
172.33.240.125 - - [20/Jul/2021:22:10:42 +0200] "GET /stack1/mockserver/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1063 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
    172.33.240.125 - - [20/Jul/2021:22:10:42 +0200] "GET /mockserver/dashboard/static/css/main.477cab2a.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "http://172.30.10.31:8080/stack1/mockserver/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
    172.33.240.125 - - [20/Jul/2021:22:10:42 +0200] "GET /mockserver/dashboard/static/js/2.1c7a191f.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "http://172.30.10.31:8080/stack1/mockserver/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
    172.33.240.125 - - [20/Jul/2021:22:10:42 +0200] "GET /mockserver/dashboard/static/js/main.14bd1bf5.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "http://172.30.10.31:8080/stack1/mockserver/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
```

And here the content of error.log

```
2021/07/20 22:10:42 [error] 235375#235375: *224273 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/mockserver/dashboard/static/css/main.477cab2a.chunk.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.33.240.125, server: 172.30.10.31, request: "GET /mockserver/dashboard/static/css/main.477cab2a.chunk.css HTTP/1.1", host: "172.30.10.31:8080", referrer: "http://172.30.10.31:8080/stack1/mockserver/dashboard/"
    2021/07/20 22:10:42 [error] 235375#235375: *224272 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/mockserver/dashboard/static/js/2.1c7a191f.chunk.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.33.240.125, server: 172.30.10.31, request: "GET /mockserver/dashboard/static/js/2.1c7a191f.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: "172.30.10.31:8080", referrer: "http://172.30.10.31:8080/stack1/mockserver/dashboard/"
    2021/07/20 22:10:42 [error] 235376#235376: *224275 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/mockserver/dashboard/static/js/main.14bd1bf5.chunk.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.33.240.125, server: 172.30.10.31, request: "GET /mockserver/dashboard/static/js/main.14bd1bf5.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: "172.30.10.31:8080", referrer: "http://172.30.10.31:8080/stack1/mockserver/dashboard/"
```

What can I do to get the dashboard of Mock Server when I acces to the Url : 172.30.10.31:8080/stack1/mockserver/dashboard ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

It seems that the dashboard is using absolute paths to load its resources.
For example:

```
<script src="/mockserver/dashboard/static/js/2.1c7a191f.chunk.js"></script>
```

You will have to rewrite the URLs in the responses to make it work, I guess...